# how to set default locale in R using mac os sierra

Tags: r, macos-sierra

I'm trying to install neuralnet package in R but gets the following error
tar:failed to set default locale

I have tried using `system("defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8")`

I have restarted R but same error

Answer (score 1):

I restarted macbook air and it was resolved

http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html#Internationalization-of-the-R_002eapp

Comment: Well done! saved hours or work!